# How can I make the distance between these rows is bigger?

Tags: spacing, equations

I am typing these inequalities with the label as follows

```
\begin{equation}\label{(4.51)}
\begin{matrix}
\la g(x_m(\tau_m(t)),u_m(\tau_m(t)) ) -g(x^{i+1}_m,u^{i+1}_m), y^n_m(t)- x_m(\tau_m(t))\ra &\leq & L' \|x_m(\tau_m(t))-x^{i+1}_m \| \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t)) \| \\
&\leq & L' K \frac{T}{m} \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t))\| \\
&\leq & L' 3K^2 \frac{T}{m} \\
&\leq &\frac{C_3}{m},
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
```

How can I make the distance between these rows is bigger? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: it would be better if you give a full working exmaple

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please read the [introductory material](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for this site. When you post a question, you are expected to provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 3):

In general, in display constructions the end of line marker `\\` takes an optional argument specifying extra vertical space that may be added.  So you can write

```
\\[1ex]
```

instead of just `\\` to get one `ex` of extra space.  Adding this to your code for each line removes the crampedness.  However, you are using the wrong environment for a multiline display.  `matrix` is for ordinary matrices with equally spaced entries.  You should be using environments from the `amsmath` package or the superset `mathtools`.  In this case a `split` inside an `equation` is most appropriate.

The document below contains four equations.  The first with roughly your original coding, very cramped.  The second with your coding with `\\[1ex]` added, this is better vertical spacing but the mathematics is still typeset in a too compact style on each line, and placement of the inequality signs is not good.  The third gives a standard `split` inside `equation` and I have used `mathtools`' command `\MoveEqLeft` to get good positioning of the first line.  The final equation is the `equation+split` with extra vertical spacing, which should not really be necessary any more.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{(4.51)}
\begin{matrix}
&&\langle g(x_m(\tau_m(t)),u_m(\tau_m(t)) ) -g(x^{i+1}_m,u^{i+1}_m),
y^n_m(t)- x_m(\tau_m(t))\rangle \\
&\leq & L' \|x_m(\tau_m(t))-x^{i+1}_m \| \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t)) \| \\
&\leq & L' K \frac{T}{m} \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t))\| \\
&\leq & L' 3K^2 \frac{T}{m} \\
&\leq &\frac{C_3}{m},
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:orig-spaced}
\begin{matrix}
&&\langle g(x_m(\tau_m(t)),u_m(\tau_m(t)) ) -g(x^{i+1}_m,u^{i+1}_m),
y^n_m(t)- x_m(\tau_m(t))\rangle \\[1ex]
&\leq & L' \|x_m(\tau_m(t))-x^{i+1}_m \| \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t)) \| \\[1ex]
&\leq & L' K \frac{T}{m} \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t))\| \\[1ex]
&\leq & L' 3K^2 \frac{T}{m} \\[1ex]
&\leq &\frac{C_3}{m},
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:split}
  \begin{split}
    \MoveEqLeft
    \langle g(x_m(\tau_m(t)),u_m(\tau_m(t)) ) -g(x^{i+1}_m,u^{i+1}_m),
    y^n_m(t)- x_m(\tau_m(t))\rangle \\
    &\leq  L' \|x_m(\tau_m(t))-x^{i+1}_m \| \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t)) \| \\
    &\leq  L' K \frac{T}{m} \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t))\| \\
    &\leq  L' 3K^2 \frac{T}{m} \\
    &\leq \frac{C_3}{m},
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:space}
  \begin{split}
    \MoveEqLeft
    \langle g(x_m(\tau_m(t)),u_m(\tau_m(t)) ) -g(x^{i+1}_m,u^{i+1}_m),
    y^n_m(t)- x_m(\tau_m(t))\rangle \\[1ex]
    &\leq  L' \|x_m(\tau_m(t))-x^{i+1}_m \| \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t)) \| \\[1ex]
    &\leq  L' K \frac{T}{m} \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t))\| \\[1ex]
    &\leq  L' 3K^2 \frac{T}{m} \\
    &\leq \frac{C_3}{m},
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am *guessing* that this is what you might be looking for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\MoveEqLeft\left( g(x_m(\tau_m(t)),u_m(\tau_m(t)) ) -g(x^{i+1}_m,u^{i+1}_m), y^n_m(t)-
x_m(\tau_m(t))\right) \notag\\
&~\leq~  L' \|x_m(\tau_m(t))-x^{i+1}_m \| \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t)) \| \notag\\
&~\leq~ L' K \frac{T}{m} \| y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t))\| \notag\\
&~\leq~ L' 3K^2 \frac{T}{m} \notag\\
&~\leq~\frac{C_3}{m}\;,\label{(4.51)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I replace `\la` and `\ra` by what I guessed they might stand for. You should *not* use `matrix` if you are typing equations. Notice that this is a so-called minimal working example, i.e. a compilable code, which you are always supposed to provide in questions.

Comment: That's the way to do it, except for the `~` signs you put in there. They make the spacing around the inequalities too large, just like bad old `eqalign` ([see this ancient answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197)).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Sorry, the `~` signs are there for a reason. I am aware of some people not liking them, but I really prefer readable equations. Note that the old `eqnarray` environment had similar spacings, but this environment is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses an `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{(4.51)}
\begin{aligned}[b]
&\bigl\langle g(x_m(\tau_m(t)),u_m(\tau_m(t)) ) -g(x^{i+1}_m,u^{i+1}_m), y^n_m(t)- x_m(\tau_m(t))\bigr\rangle \\
&\qquad\leq L' \norm[\big]{x_m(\tau_m(t))-x^{i+1}_m} \norm[\big]{ y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t))} \\
&\qquad\leq L' K \frac{T}{m} \norm[\big]{y^n_m(t)-x_m(\tau_m(t))} \\
&\qquad\leq L' 3K^2 \frac{T}{m} \\
&\qquad\leq \frac{C_3}{m}\,.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```